# difference between creating data base in microsoft access using netbeans and creating database in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-connection

what is the difference between creating data base in microsoft access using netbeans and creating database in mysql. is it the same ? Please help me.. i dun understand.

Answer (score 0):

No. At any stage, it is totally different. `Microsoft Access` and `MySQL` are 2 different platforms.

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft Access` and `MYSQL` are two different platforms for storing database. They both have their respective ways of storing and manipulating data.